# How to get the text between tags in a xml, using preferably lxml

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

This is an example of the tag, but I can't get the text between tags, not iterating over the tags, not with node.text in the node `<seg>`. That's why I'm asking, all the help will be welcome (sorry for my english).

```
    <tuv>
         <seg>If you want to save items in a 
            <bpt i="1">&lt;Message id=&quot;Message:1T0000772343:f000012900ce8eb3:MPhS&quot;&gt;</bpt>
            <ept i="1">&lt;/Message&gt;</ept> 
            for which no connection has been established or in a 
            <bpt i="2">&lt;Message id=&quot;Message:1T0000772343:f000012900ceac3d:pvy4&quot;&gt;</bpt>
            <ept i="2">&lt;/Message&gt;</ept> 
            that requires authentication, you need to connect to the library.
         </seg>
   </tuv>
```

Wanted Output:

If you want to save items in a for which no connection has been established or in a that requires authentication, you need to connect to the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.xpath("text()")` on the `<seg>` element to get all text nodes.

This code prints the wanted output:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.parse("tuv.xml")  
seg = root.find("seg")

# Get the text nodes of 'seg' as one string
text = " ".join(t for t in seg.xpath("text()"))

# Print result with unwanted whitespace removed
print " ".join(text.split())
```

Comment: Note that `seg.text` is just this bit: "If you want to save items in a ". The rest of the text content is available via the `tail` of the `<ept>`children of `<seg>`. See http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#tail.